# Attach RX observable to input box

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I'm new to RXJS and I'm trying to attach an RX observable to an input box. So far I have the following code which works...

```
$onInit() {
    this.$timeout(() => {
        let $input = document.getElementById('input_33');
        const weeks$ = this.rx.Observable.fromEvent($input, 'keyup');
        const queries$ = weeks$
            .map(e => e.target.value)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .debounce(500);

        queries$.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
    });
}
```

So the code above will console log the value of the #input_33 on keyup.

I've had to add the $timeout to wait for the input to appear in the DOM. Is there a better way to do it as I'd rather not have to use timeout? I'm using Angular 1.5x

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are wrong in implement rx programming. observer automatic called when an event from observable occur.

You shouldn't use $timeout to wait for the input to appear in the DOM. You can put code in the controller because when controller get called the DOM Ready already fired so input field already available.